# Display screen to only new users react navigation v3

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I would like to know how I would go about implementing a welcome/getting started screen using react navigation v3.

My confusion would be where the welcome/getting started screen would go?
should the screen be in the Appstack or Authstack?

I want to display this to new users only. When a user logs out and re-authenticate I want it to be popped out of the stack because they are not new users and take them directly to the main app.

I think this piece of logic should take place in the Authloadingscreen, am just not sure how or what technique to use.

This is an example Appfrom https://snack.expo.io/@react-navigation/auth-flow-v3

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  ActivityIndicator,
  AsyncStorage,
  Button,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

class SignInScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Please sign in',
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button title="Sign in!" onPress={this._signInAsync} />
      </View>
    );
  }

  _signInAsync = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('userToken', 'abc');
    this.props.navigation.navigate('App');
  };
}

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Welcome to the app!',
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button title="Show me more of the app" onPress={this._showMoreApp} />
        <Button title="Actually, sign me out :)" onPress={this._signOutAsync} />
      </View>
    );
  }

  _showMoreApp = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Other');
  };

  _signOutAsync = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.clear();
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Auth');
  };
}

class OtherScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Lots of features here',
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button title="I'm done, sign me out" onPress={this._signOutAsync} />
        <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
      </View>
    );
  }

  _signOutAsync = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.clear();
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Auth');
  };
}

class AuthLoadingScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this._bootstrapAsync();
  }

  // Fetch the token from storage then navigate to our appropriate place
  _bootstrapAsync = async () => {
    const userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');

    // This will switch to the App screen or Auth screen and this loading
    // screen will be unmounted and thrown away.
    this.props.navigation.navigate(userToken ? 'App' : 'Auth');
  };

  // Render any loading content that you like here
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ActivityIndicator />
        <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

const AppStack = createStackNavigator({ Home: HomeScreen, Other: OtherScreen });
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({ SignIn: SignInScreen });

export default createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
    App: AppStack,
    Auth: AuthStack,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
  }
));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put this in the AppStack, since it is part of your app content and not part of your authentication flow.

Additionally, you need a way to determine if it's a new user or a returning user. So either you store this information server side, or locally using AsyncStorage. The best approach would be to store this information server side, since a user can always get a new phone. So during loading (if authenticated) or authenticating you make sure you fetch that data and display/hide the welcome screen accordingly.